# Lazy Evaluation in Visual Studio Hover Watch

Tags: visual-studio

I have just seen a strange thing happen on Visual Studio 2013 (Professional) and don’t know what it is. Let’s say I’m declaring a class having one field and one property as so :

[image]

And I use it like so : `A a = new A();`

So when I run it and watch the value in Hover Watch,  I see :

[image]

Note the value of both _number and Number.

If now, I do nothing, hover out of the hover watch and hover in again, I see this :

[image]

I don’t understand why it is not updating the value of _number earlier. Can anybody suggest as to what is happening here ??

Comment: I can't reproduce this in VS2015.  Maybe it's just time to upgrade? What's holding you back? :)

Comment: @PedroG.Dias: It is because I'm on a corporate network and I cannot upgrade it as i desire...:)

Comment: That is weird, as project compatibility swings both ways between 2013 and 2015, but yeah, some corporations eh? :)